# Python function variable assignment with self-defined class

Tags: python, immutability

why is it that replaceNode1 works but replaceNode2 doesn't? I thought about mutability but None is mutable. Thank you for your time

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

def replaceNode1():
    node = [None]
    def doit(val, node):
        node[0] = Node(val)
    doit(20, node)
    return node[0].val    # return 20

def replaceNode2():
    node = None
    def doit(val, node):
        node = Node(val)
    doit(20, node)
    return node.val      # return 'NoneType' has no attribute 'val'
```

Comment: Because if you assign to a variable in a function, that is a local variable. In the first example, you do not assign to a variable, you assign to an *element* of a variable. So that is not locally scoped. Lists are frequently used in Python to emulate *call-by-reference*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The assignment operator in python is not doing what you think it is doing. I hope this helps elucidate that:

Let's say you create a list object with None as it's only element and get its memory location with `id` :

```
>>> node = [None]

>>> id(node)

4397969352
```

Now you change it's first value:

```
>>> node[0] = 100

>>> print(node[0])

100

>>> id(node)

4397969352
```

The memory location of the list *has not changed* (however the memory location of it's first element has). When you change the value of *a variable name*, python assigns the name of the variable to another memory location:

```
>>> node = None

>>> id(node)

4394834344

>>> node = Node(10)

>>> id(node)

4397990184
```

As you can see above, node now points to a different place in memory.

So in your code, where you call the function replaceNode2, you assign the **local-variable** *node* to a new Node object, which points to a new memory location, while the *node* in the **parent-scope** still points to the original memory location **and is still of a NoneType object**. That is why you get that error. Not because of the mutability of a NoneType object, but rather due to the way python assigns objects to names and the way variable-scopes work.